# Efficient way to simplify `E^(x (Log[a]/x + Log[b]/x))` to `a b`

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I would have expected `PowerExpand` to simplify expressions like `E^(x (Log[a]/x + Log[b]/x))` to the expected outcome `a b`, yet it doesn't.

**I'm looking for the 'least-simplifying' function that achieves this simplification.**

(In the case I'm really interested it there might be more than two terms in the sum in the exponential, and the expressions consist of several of such exponentials along with various other functions.)

In the following example `PowerExpand` never works, `Factor` works for sufficiently simple `x`, and `Simplify` always works:

```
E^(x (Log[a]/x + Log[b]/x))             // {PowerExpand@#, Factor@#, Simplify@#} &
E^(\[Pi] (Log[a]/\[Pi] + Log[b]/\[Pi])) // {PowerExpand@#, Factor@#, Simplify@#} &
E^(I (-I Log[a] - I Log[b]))            // {PowerExpand@#, Factor@#, Simplify@#} &
E^(2 (Log[a]/2 + Log[b]/2))             // {PowerExpand@#, Factor@#, Simplify@#} &
```

giving

```
(* Out: *)

{E^(x (Log[a]/x + Log[b]/x)), E^(x (Log[a]/x + Log[b]/x)), a b}
{E^(\[Pi] (Log[a]/\[Pi] + Log[b]/\[Pi])), E^(\[Pi] (Log[a]/\[Pi] + Log[b]/\[Pi])), a b}
{E^(I (-I Log[a] - I Log[b])), a b, a b}
{E^(2 (Log[a]/2 + Log[b]/2)), a b, a b}
```

However, in the examples I am really working with, `Factor` does not work, while `Simplify` spends a lot of time on manipulations that I don't want it to try.

Comment: `ExpandAll` works for each of your examples.

Comment: @BobHanlon Great, that's what I was after! If you formulate it as an answer I'll happily accept it

Comment: However, using `AbsoluteTiming` or `RepeatedTiming`, `Simplify` is much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ExpandAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpandAll.html) works for each example

```
RepeatedTiming[ExpandAll[#]] & /@
 {E^(x (Log[a]/x + Log[b]/x)),
  E^(π (Log[a]/π + Log[b]/π)),
  E^(I (-I Log[a] - I Log[b])),
  E^(2 (Log[a]/2 + Log[b]/2))}

(* {{0.000129465, a b}, {0.000147345, a b}, {0.000141611, 
  a b}, {0.000128871, a b}} *)
```

However, [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) is much faster for these examples

```
RepeatedTiming[Simplify[#]] & /@
 {E^(x (Log[a]/x + Log[b]/x)),
  E^(π (Log[a]/π + Log[b]/π)),
  E^(I (-I Log[a] - I Log[b])),
  E^(2 (Log[a]/2 + Log[b]/2))}

(* {{6.24617*10^-6, a b}, {6.55825*10^-6, a b}, {6.57978*10^-6, 
  a b}, {6.61765*10^-6, a b}} *)
```

Comment: The expressions that I really work with are more complicated, and `ExpandAll` takes .5s in a case where `Simplify` gave the warning 'exceeded 300s trying to simplify', so I am very happy with your solution!  (The check hinged on simplifying the exponentials, rather than trying to simplify other parts of the expression.)

Comment: I'm glad it worked out.